# migrating content from EE1 to EE2 with Structure and Datagrab

Tags: structure, file-uploads, ee1, ee2-upgrades, datagrab

I've been working on a horrible EE1 installation and bring it into EE2. Unfortunately it was one of those sites that decided to use Gypsy, oh and Structure and just to make things interesting, MX Uni Editor's file field.

The upgrade went relatively smoothly actually, although Gypsy was used throughout there were only a handful of channels so was able to just have 1 field group in the EE2 site and share it amongst channels.

The Structure upgrade went smoothly also.

Where we fell down was the assignment of images and attachments to entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We created an XML feed of all channels (we couldn't automatically export because http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/weblog-entries-exporter doesn't support Gypsy).

We then used Datagrab to import the XML feeds respectively. Datagrab did a great job of mapping the Matrix rows of MX Uni Editor file fields to Assets 2 fields on 'news' and 'press release'. However, when we did the same thing for the 'page' channel that Structure uses as a general page type, it would blow out the Structure settings.

The simple way around this for us was to temporarily change the 'page' channel to an asset type in the Structure settings, run the import, confirm the images/attachments were properly assigned and then revert that channel back to being a page.

It took a few attempts before we realised the import was screwing the parent Structure entries.

Comment: I've used the 'Undo Gypsy' migration tool successfully quite a few times. And all addons that are not EE2 compatible I either convert to text first, or change to EE2 compatible addon. We updated 'Undo Gypsy' a while back to tackle Matrix fields too:

https://github.com/litzinger/UndoGypsy.eeaddon/

Comment: Thanks Brendan. Quick question re Undo Gypsy. Where you map weblogs/channels to field group id like https://gist.github.com/stevieg83/6131920 am I right in saying that the first number in that array is the weblog/channel id and the second is the newly created field group id?

Comment: Yep, that's correct. If you have nGen File Field used though, do the conversion of those first.

Comment: Cheers, yeah seems I'm in a little bit of a jam. I've got a weblog called 'static' which has its own field group as well as pulling in other fields from other channels. Its own field group also extends other channels so when I run the script, it transfers the other channel fields but not its own. Pretty funky :-(

Comment: That sort of sounds like it's doing what it's meant to do. If you chose to use a different channel field group rather than the original, it would transfer and copy all fields into it I guess. It's certainly not a silver bullet, but it's still pretty good.

Comment: Thanks man. Yeah I eventually just created the additional field and then ran UPDATE exp_weblog_data SET field_id_X=field_id_Y WHERE weblog_id='Z' where X is the new field, Y is the old Gypsy field and Z is the weblog.