# Exporting/importing Structure entries within the same site

Tags: structure, solspace, import, export, solspace-importer

I've got a channel that will need to be copied, and it's part of the Structure add-on/hierarchy.

Is it possible to copy/migrate the Structure data along with other custom field data to a new channel using DataGrab or Solspace Importer?

P.S. Here's a possible solution: [migrating content from EE1 to EE2 with Structure and Datagrab](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/12290/migrating-content-from-ee1-to-ee2-with-structure-and-datagrab/12291#12291)

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen an add-on that will do this, since the URLs would be different anyway.

Comment: Just a quick note to say that Importer does not support Structure data import as of this writing.